# Why doesn't water get 'increasingly thicker' as it gets colder?

Tags: temperature, water, ice

It's my understanding that the colder liquids get (or anything else for that matter) the slower the constituting particles move.
That being the case, why is H$_2$O either 'water' or 'ice'?
Given that temperature is continuous, why isn't there a continual physical change depending on temperature?

Comment: Why should there be a "continuous change"? Different phases are mostly *defined* by such discontinuous changes - look up what a *phase transition* is.

Comment: @ACuriousMind That's a textbook example of [begging the question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beg_a_question).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Water, like most liquids does indeed get more viscous as its temperature approaches freezing point. See the graph below, which I took from the ["Engineering Toolbox"](http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/water-dynamic-kinematic-viscosity-d_596.html)

However, what's interesting about this curve is that it does not diverge as $T\to 0^\circ{\rm C}$. The reason is that a phase change really is for all effective purposes a discontinuous phenomenon: at $0+\epsilon^\circ{\rm C}$ the water molecules have enough kinetic energy to avoid binding to one another in a solid lattice: at $0-\epsilon^\circ{\rm C}$ they do not and this argument holds for any $\epsilon>0$. Otherwise put: the freezing point is an energy *threshold* in the same way that the behavior of a body in the neighborhood of the Earth shows behaviors that are similarly discontinuous functions of the body's total energy: if the body's speed energy exceeds the escape velocity at a point by an arbitrarily small amount, the body will follow a hyperbolic path and leave the neighborhood forever: lower the speed to an arbitrarily small amount below escape velocity and the path will be elliptic and the motion periodic: the path topologies change discontinuously from noncompact to compact.

[image]

Comment: About 325 BC Pytheas of Massalia sailed into the North Atlantic, a region "where land properly speaking no longer exists, nor sea nor air, but a mixture of these things, like a [jellyfish], in which it is said that earth and water and all things are in suspension as if this something was a link between all these elements, on which one can neither walk nor sail. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pytheas).  Apparently he sailed into temperatures approaching 0 degC.

Comment: @Ernie Very interesting, although the account in Wikipedia seems to suggest instead slush: a mixture of liquid water and ice particles and vapor (in the air above) at its triple point.